# django-models: Error when trying to add a calculated field to a model with foreign keys

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to add a "maintenance_payable" field that is calulated by multiplying two other fields to a "Unit" model

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    given_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.EmailField(
        unique=True, 
        error_messages={
            'unique':'Thie email has already ben registered'
        }
        )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['given_name', 
'family_name'], name='unique_owner'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.preferred_name


class Unit(models.Model):
    property=models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    floor=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    unit_number=models.CharField(max_length=10)   
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    share_value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    ownership_start_date=models.DateField()
    maintenance_fee_monthly = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sinking_fund_monthly = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


@property
    def maintenance_payable(self):
    return (self.maintenance_fee_monthly * self.share_value)/100
```

when I tried to save the model.py, I get the error, TypeError: 'ForeignKey' object is not callable. Please help. Great Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A model field declares the format of the value that is stored in database. As the type of your wanted field is a normal numeric value and not a relation to another model, a normal `FloatField` is enough. The `ForeignKey` is used to link to another model (that you do not have).

The `clean`method is running before saving the model to the database. There for example errors will be thrown if you input a string to a `PositiveIntegerField`. This runs in `super().clean()`. **Be careful**, you assign the value after the django clean method. So if your computation somehow results in a format that does not fit to `FloatField` it will probably not be covered by the `clean`method (because it runs before!)

Read here the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to find this quote

> you could use it to automatically provide a value for a field

```py
class Unit(models.Model):
    multiplied_field = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    block = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    unit_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)   
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    share_value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    ownership_start_date = models.DateField()
    maintenance_fee_monthly = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sinking_fund_monthly = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    self.multiplied_field = (self.maintenance_fee_monthly * self.share_value)/100
```

If you do not want users to be able to edit that field (e.g. in a form) you could go for either:
`multiplied_field = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)` or in your model form you would need to `exclude = ["multiplied_field"]`

Comment: Great thanks.  I actually have an "Owner" model. Hence the foreign key.  Having used the clean() method, how can I access  "multiplied_field" in a template. Accesssing it via "unit.multiplied_field" does not seem to work. (in a loop, "for unit in units:" where units is Unit.objects.all()). Great thanks

Comment: I was talking about your usage of `ForeignKey` in your second line of your presented code, which is wrong, which I corrected. For **newly** created `Unit`s you should be able to show `{{ unit.multiplied_field }}`. Your old `Unit`s do not have that field yet, because you just recently introduced that field.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to perfom the calculations using mathfilters in the form template which looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load mathfilters %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Unit List</h1>
            <hr class="my-4">
            {% block content %}
            <form class="d-flex" role="search" action="{% url 'billing-list' %}">
            
                <input class="form-control me-2" 
                    type="search" 
                    placeholder="Search for OWNER, PROPERTY, BLK or UNIT NUMBER" 
                    aria-label="Search" 
                    name="search">

                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>


           
    
            <table class="table table-borderless">
                <thead class="border-bottom font-weight-bold">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Property Name</td>
                        <td>Block</td>
                        <td>Floor Number</td>
                        <td>Unit Number</td>
                        <td>Owner</td>
                        <td>Share Value</td>
                        <td>Ownership Start Date</td>
                        <td>Monthly Maintenance Fee Payable</td>
                        <td>Monthly Sinking Fund Payable</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{% url 'pdf-list' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                                <i class="fa-thin fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF
                            </a>
                            <a href="{% url 'email' %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i> Email
                            </a>
                        </td>

                  
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for unit in unit_list %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{unit.property}}</td>
                            <td>{{unit.block}}</td>
                            <td>{{unit.floor}}</td>
                            <td>{{unit.unit_number}}</td>
                            <td>{{unit.owner}}</td>
                            <td>{{unit.share_value}}</td>
                            <td>{{unit.ownership_start_date}}</td>

                            {% with unit.maintenance_fee_monthly as maint %} 
                                {% with unit.share_value as share %} 
                                    <td>{{maint|mul:share|div:100}}</td>
                                {% endwith %}
                            {% endwith %}

                            {% with unit.sinking_fund_monthly as sink %} 
                                {% with unit.share_value as share %} 
                                    <td>{{sink|mul:share|div:100}}</td>
                                {% endwith %}
                            {% endwith %}
                                                    
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}     
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="7"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>{{maint_total}}</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>{{sink_total}}</strong></td>
                    </tr>               
                </tbody>
            </table>


            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's working now. Great Thanks